# Pipe dynamic PDF into Imagemagick and convert to PNG

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, pipe

I need to create thumbnails from dynamic (database driven) pdf's.  I've used a variation of the script below in the past, but this doesn't seem to be working for me now (page just hangs).

```
<?php
 require_once('./template/all_includes.php');

 $descriptorspec = array(
  0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
  1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
  2 => array("pipe", "w")   // stderr is a file to write to
 );

 $cwd = '/tmp';
 $env = array('asdfadf' => '193');

 $convert = "convert pdf:- png:-";
 $process = proc_open($convert, $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);

    fwrite($pipes[0], 'php /var/www/html/domain.co.uk/store/pdf.php');
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    while(!feof($pipes[1])) $im .= fread($pipes[1], 1024);
    fclose($pipes[1]);

    $return_value = proc_close($process);

 header("Content-Type: image/png");
 echo $im;

   ?>
```

Could anyone help me out with this please?  Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Magick can open PDFs natively:

```
$im = new MagickWand('file.pdf[3]');  // open page 3 of the PDF
$png = $im->whateverTheMethodIsForPNG();
```

Comment: I want to avoid the API's as the performance hit is significant over using exec()

Comment: I wasn't very clear.  Using the PHP Native API's is a significant performance hit over using the command line (via exec or similar).  Hence my need to use the method I outlined.

Comment: Running something thru exec() and a native API will be the same speed if they are the same language (and there is a 80% chance it is, probably) -- C.

Comment: I worked on a project where I initially used the API's to generate dynamic styled text.  After a lot of frustration with the speed, I reverted to using command line/exec which improved the generation time to just a few hundredths of a second (from several seconds).

Not really looking to argue the point, just backing up my claims in case somebody finds it useful one day.